# What's the word for "remaining list"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's suppose there is a list of tasks ordered by due date

> past due date
>
> - change toothbrush
> - change tyres
>
> today
>
> - Go to xxx place
> - buy xxxx
>
> remaining list(which are due in future)
>
> - take dog to vet
> - some task
> - some other task

What word should I use in place of **"remaining list"(*which are due in future*)**?

Comment: "Pending" or "To-do-list".

Comment: If you're okay with "past due date" shouldn't you also be okay with "future due date"?

Comment: @Rathony +1 for _to-do list_. (It's not _to-do-list_ by the way.)

Comment: Perhaps: past due date->"Missed deadline"; today ->"Expiring today"; remaining list -> "Next scheduled tasks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not *[upcoming](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=upcoming)*?

> Occurring soon; forthcoming.

*American Heritage*

Comment: thanks, also is there a word for past due date?

Comment: Because _upcoming_ is not a very good word for a deliberate action. Upcoming things _come up_ to you. _To-do list_ is better.

Comment: *Overdue* might work.

Comment: @Fard the whole list is todo list, I am dividing the todo list by their due date